# Key Error: 0 while searching in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created the below dataframe:

```
      C1     C2  Count
0   Jack  Item1     20
1  Jones  Item1     15
```

I am trying to search for the second row with person name Jones using the below command and trying to fetch the count 15.

```
person_inq="Jones"
item_inq="Item1"    
count_in_df = df.loc[(df['C1'] == person_inq) & (df['C2'] == item_inq),'Count'][0]
```

While executing the above command, i am getting key

```
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: `df.loc[(df['C1'] == person_inq) & (df['C2'] == item_inq),'Count'].item()` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you.. yes item() worked. whats the difference between using [0] and item()?

Comment: The result of `loc` is a series slice. The series has index 1 and value 15. Now, If you try to extract `[0]`, it tries to look for the index "0" which doesn't exist in the index. [0] does not refer to the first value, unless you use `iloc` for positional indexing. So, `df.loc[(df['C1'] == person_inq) & (df['C2'] == item_inq),'Count'].iloc[0]` would have also worked.

Comment: Great.. Thank you